# What happens after gazebo issues in bitbucket is resolved

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

I have some newbie questions:

What happens after a Gazebo issue in Bitbucket is resolved?
How do i install the updated version on my machine ?
Are the resolved issues are corrected only for the most recent Gazebo version or also for the previous ones ? (As I work with ROS, I use the Gazebo 2)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9596/what-happens-after-gazebo-issues-in-bitbucket-is-resolved/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/726/dmeltz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 127 on 2015-10-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After a fix is merged in gazebo bitbucket repository, supposing that you are using Ubuntu, it will be released depending on the target branch where the fix was merged:

- In **default branch**: the change will be released in the next major version of gazebo. You can check the [schedule in gazebosim site](http://gazebosim.org/#status). Meantime, you can use our [nightly releases](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_unstable&cat=install) (with caution).
- In a **gazeboX branch**: if the patch was merged in a gazeboX (being X a number representing a major version of gazebo), the the change can be released at any time by doing a new minor/patch version. For example: a change merged in gazebo6 branch will be released in the next gazebo-6.X.Y. Feel free to request a release (using gazebo issues) if you need a pending change.

For any other cases (not using Ubuntu, can not wait for a minor bump, etc). you can always use the [build from source procedure](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install)

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmeltz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/726/dmeltz/) on 2016-04-02**:
Josh thanks, for the detailed answer